# How to find $n$-th term of a recursive sequence without matrix exponentiation?

Tags: recurrence-relations, closed-form

I want to know, is there any other way to find the $n$-th term of recursive sequence without the direct method or matrix exponentiation? Please tell me if you know. Thank you very much.

Example: $A_n = 3A_{n-1} + 4A_{n-2}, \; A_0=3, \; A_1=2$ - I want to know the method to find $A_n$ without the direct method or use matrix exponentiation.

Comment: A *scalar* recurrence relation does not require matrix exponentiation. A *vector* recurrence relation does not require matrix exponentiation if the matrix in question is nilpotent or idempotent.

Comment: Dear @RodrigodeAzevedo, please abstain from making useless edits. If you really had wanted to do something useful, you could have corrected *"have some other way"* into *"is there any aother way"*, and *"the nth of recursion sequence"* into *"the nth term of the recursive sequence"*, and *"naive method"* into "*the naive method"*, and put a question mark. And if you decided to put `$` signs around $n$ in the title, you could have done it in the body too. And you could have eliminated the tags *(linear-algebra)* and *(functions)*, because they are not relevant to the question.

Comment: I want to know another ways faster then this method in this link. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FibonacciQ-Matrix.html

Comment: Question is hard to understand. What does "find the $n$th of recursion sequence" mean? What's the "naive method"? Please edit the question to add this information.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Let's not be mean, it is obvious that the OP is not a native English speaker. The naive method is computing the terms one by one until reaching the desired one - not only is it exponentially slow, but it also does not allow one to have a closed form for the $n$-th term.

Comment: @Alex, now that I know what the question is, I'm sure it should be closed as a duplicate. It has been asked here many times before.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following recursion:

$$x_{n+k} = a_{k-1} x_{n+k-1} + \dots + a_0 x_n$$

with $x_0, \dots, x_{k-1}$ and $a_0, \dots, a_{k-1}$ given.

The first step is to solve the associated algebraic equation obtained by formally replacing $x_{n-i}$ in the recurrence formula by $r^i$:

$$r^k = a_{k-1} r^{k-1} + \dots + a_1 r + a_0 .$$

If $r_1, \dots, r_p$ are the roots, each one with multiplicity $m_1, \dots, m_p$, then the general solution of the recurrence is

$$x_n = \sum _{i=1} ^p \sum _{j=1} ^{m_p} \alpha_{ij} \ n^{j-1} r_i ^n .$$

In order to find out the values of the coefficients $\alpha_{ij}$, solve the $k$-dimensional linear system

$$\begin{cases}
x_0 &=& \sum _{i=1} ^p \sum _{j=1} ^{m_p} \alpha_{ij} \ n^{j-1} \\
x_1 &=& \sum _{i=1} ^p \sum _{j=1} ^{m_p} \alpha_{ij} \ n^{j-1} r_i ^1 \\
\vdots \\
x_{k-1} &=& \sum _{i=1} ^p \sum _{j=1} ^{m_p} \alpha_{ij} \ n^{j-1} r_i ^{k-1} .
\end{cases}$$

Of course, solving a general $k$-th degree algebraic equation is not going to be easy...